# Difference between had been and went to

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, grammaticality-in-context

What is the difference between *had been* and *went to*?

When can I use—

> I had been to that temple.

And when can I use—

> I went to that temple.

Comment: "I went" is the simple past.  "I had been" is the past perfect.  So if you look up when to use the simple past and when to use past perfect, that should answer most of your question.

Comment: @Suraj - When you ask a question, consider waiting a while before you accept an answer. Often the best answer will come after many readers have read your question, so give them time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can say both but when you say "I went" is in simple past and this tense refers when an action happened in the past and finishes in the past. The past perfect is "I had been" and it refers to an action that takes place before a certain time in the past, example: Before I came here, I had spoken to Manuel.

On the other hand, I would put "I had been in that temple".